# C# Excel VSTO prevent texbox to lose focus on range selection

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am writing an Excel VSTO. I have an Application level Custom Task Pane with 2 TextBoxes. I would like to handle the SheetSelectionChange event to write selected range address in the textboxes. My problem is that once I click on the Worksheet to select a range, the textbox I selected before loose the focus and I cannot write the address of the selected range to the correct Texbox.

Is there a way to prevent the Textbox to loose the focus while selecting a range? Or is there any other workaround this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Each time a textbox is selected, store a reference to it so you can write the address to the correct one.  If you can share the relevant parts of your code people might have more-specific suggestions...

Comment: That is exactly what I finally did.